# What is the appropriate logical expression for "hold where"?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

If we write a statement like "A holds where B", then does it mean $A \iff B$ or only $B \Rightarrow A$?

Comment: $A \iff B$ is meant A holds where and olny where  B, so the second answer is good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A  bit of an unusual expression ... did you run into a concrete use of it?  English is ambiguous, so oftentimes context and background knowledge can tell you what is meant. Still, if I had to choose between them, I would pick the one-way conditional: .. if I wanted the biconditional, I would have used something like 'A holds exactly where B holds' ... or 'A holds where, and only where, B holds'.  But a simple 'A holds where B holds' suggests to me $B \to A$

Comment: And if there's a comma before "where", then it might even mean `A and B`: for example, "$`c^2 \ge 0$ holds, where $c\in[-3,7]$". But yes, ambiguous; better to rephrase it.

Comment: @ryang Nice example :)

Comment: Specifically, I wondered using "hold where" is enough or not to state biconditional for $||x-y||=0 \Leftrightarrow x-y=0$.
According to your answer, then it would not be enough.